# ArcGIS Online last viewed date for items in organization

Tags: python, arcgis-online, administration

I am trying to make a notebook that will give an output of all the content in our organization that hasn't been viewed/used in the last 5 years and can't find the right attribute to pull the date from.
I was able to make one for modified/edited in the last 5 years, but we care about what has been opened not what has been edited.

Is this something that is possible to pull using Python?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the two date attributes "created" and "modified" exist at every element in ArcGIS Enterprise / ArcGIS Online. Since November 2022 the attribute "lastViewed" shall also exist in ArcGIS Online, which contains the date of the last access.
These attributes can be queried from the Portal REST interface via Python. In ArcGIS Enterprise I have observed that the attribute is also included since version 11.1, but it is assigned the value "-1" for all elements and could therefore not yet be used successfully by me.

See also the documentation for the ArcGIS REST API: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/item.htm